# Configure Clock on different port other than port 80 in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

I installed CentOS 6.4 & noticed that port 80 is being used by Clock application

```
[root@l-22733-p11 logs]# lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND     PID      USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
clock-app 10418 jack   21u  IPv4 408998      0t0  TCP l-22733-p11.abc.com:51095->a23-3-105-136.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:http (CLOSE_WAIT)
clock-app 20477 jack   21u  IPv4 408354      0t0  TCP l-22733-p11.abc.com:51088->a23-3-105-136.deploy.akamaitechnologies.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

If I kill these processes, then the clock gets killed.

How can I configure this clock to run on different port than port 80? This issue was not present with earlier version of CentOS.

I want to run the Tomcat server on port 80 & it is giving me bind exception since clock is running on port 80.

Comment: fwiw, most people on Centos run tomcat as the user `tomcat` and so if you've configured it to listen on port 80 and it's borking out, you might be running into the fact that a non-root account is attempting to connect to a privileged port (port below 1024). If that's what's going on, you have three choices: 1) find a way to get the `tomcat` user to have `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` 2) switch to run tomcat under root or 3) leave tomcat on 8080 and do a reverse proxy through Apache httpd to the ajp port (IIRC port 8009) via mod_ajp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the results, `clock-app` connects to a website and is not listening on port 80.